# php calculates wrong date

Tags: php, date, timestamp

The following code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$timestamp = strtotime('13.03.2017');
echo $timestamp.' '.date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $timestamp).'<br>';
$timestamp += 7*24*60*60;
echo $timestamp.' '.date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $timestamp).'<br>';
$timestamp += 7*24*60*60;
echo $timestamp.' '.date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $timestamp).'<br>';
```

leads to this output:

```
1489359600 13.03.2017 00:00:00
1489964400 20.03.2017 00:00:00
1490569200 27.03.2017 01:00:00
```

The last line should bi `1490569200 27.03.2017 00:00:00`, so I'm asking myself what went wrong. Is this a php-bug?
What can I do to get an correct output?

Comment: Remember: the daylight saving time starts on 26th of march ;)

Comment: Change this `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');` to `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` and the numbers will be calc'd correctly

Comment: what is wrong with your o/p ?